# Explanation of some simple constructor code

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm slightly confused on what happens if I do the following:

```
class a{
  int i;
public:
  a(){}
};

class b: public a{
};

int main(){
  b  b1;
}
```

Since class `b` has no constructor, what constructor does it use? Does it use default constructor of `a`? Or its very own compiler generated one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since class b has no constructor, what constructor does it use? Does it use default constructor of a? Or its very own compiler generated one?

This is a little bit trickier than it may at first seem.

In terms of the C++ Standard, classes get compiler-generated constructors taking no arguments when the programmer doesn't explicitly specify a constructor.  Conceptually, `b` gets such a default constructor which in turn invokes the constructor of `a`.

At another level, in an optimising compiler neither constructor has anything to do - they may (or may not) be completely eliminated and "not exist" even as an empty function.  So - at this level - talk about `b`'s constructor calling `a`'s constructor is just nonsense.

IMHO, it's important to understand both aspects.

Answer (score 5):

There are two constructors that will be called - first constructor `a` for the base class initialization, then constructor `b`. Since you didn't define a constructor for `b` the compiler generated a default one for you. Since your `b` class doesn't have any members that need constructing, that default constructor will be empty.

Answer (score 4):

It has a compiler-generated "defaulted" default (zero argument) constructor and a compiler-generated "defaulted" copy constructor.  It also has a compiler-generated "defaulted" move constructor, if your compiler supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Class b will have a compiler-generated constructor, which will in turn call the constructor of a.

Answer (score 1):

`class b` will have a default constructor generated by the compiler. Because `b` inherits `a`, the order will first construct `a`, and then `b`.